# What type of URL is chrome://?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

What type of link is Chrome://, Edge:// and Steam:// ?

I have tried to search this in Internet but couldn't find it and also how can I create a URL like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These URIs are custom app url handlers. These URLs will be resolved from the Browser at OS level where the browser will query the OS what to execute. After gathering the information, the browser will then attempt to open a specific application with the URI as parameter.

To create such URI, you need to define the handler, which depends on the OS. Here are a few examples:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app
- https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app